# Proof for equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, equivalence-relations

I have to prove that this is an equivalence relation:
$B R C := A \cap B = A \cap C$

I do unterstand that I would then have to prove that this is reflexive, symmetrical and transitive, but I don't know how. 
Can anyone help me, I would be very grateful,

Thank you

Comment: All three happen to be pretty easy because set equality is an equivalence relation, so you can hijack that fact.

Comment: Given two sets $A, B$ the sets are equal if $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$. Trying using that

Answer (score 1):

Reflexive:
$BRB$ because $A \cap B= A \cap B$ this is trivial (think which elements are in right, are they in the left also? What about the other possibility?

Symmetric:

$BRC$ should imply$CRB$

This is true because $A \cap B= A \cap C$ and this implies the other way ($A \cap C= A \cap B$ (nothing has changed, think about how switching orders of intersections doesn’t change anything)

Transitive:

$BRC$ and $CRD$ should imply $BRD$

Well, if intersection $A$ and $B$ is equal to intersection $A$ and $C$ and intersection $A$ and $D$ is equal to intersection $A$ and $C$, this could mean only one thing (what does it mean)?

Please show some work if you need help/ point out where exactly you need help with.